# Scaling in scikit-learn permutation_test_score

Tags: scikit-learn, permutation, cross-validation, standardized

I'm using the scikit-learn "permutation_test_score" method to evaluate my estimator performances significance. Unfortunately, I cannot understand from the scikit-learn documentation if the method implements any scaling on data. I use to standardise my data through a StandardScaler, to apply the training set standardisation to the testing set.

Comment: see my answer and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The function itself does not apply any scaling.

**Here is an example from the documentation:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import permutation_test_score
from sklearn import datasets


iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
n_classes = np.unique(y).size

# Some noisy data not correlated
random = np.random.RandomState(seed=0)
E = random.normal(size=(len(X), 2200))

# Add noisy data to the informative features for make the task harder
X = np.c_[X, E]

svm = SVC(kernel='linear')
cv = StratifiedKFold(2)

score, permutation_scores, pvalue = permutation_test_score(
    svm, X, y, scoring="accuracy", cv=cv, n_permutations=100, n_jobs=1)
```

### However, what you may want to do is to pass in the `permutation_test_score` a `pipeline` where you apply the scaling.

**Example:**

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

pipe = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('clf', SVC(kernel='linear'))])
score, permutation_scores, pvalue = permutation_test_score(
        pipe, X, y, scoring="accuracy", cv=cv, n_permutations=100, n_jobs=1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much seralouk. It is the solution I was searching for.